# MariaDB OpeLDAP authentication works locally, not remotely?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, openldap, mariadb

I have MySQL (MariaDB) setup on Ubuntu 14.04 to authenticate users from our OpenLDAP instance using the documentation [here](https://planet.mysql.com/entry/?id=5991634).  When I ssh into the server and issue `mysql -u user101 -p` I can authenticate just fine (user101 is an LDAP user; does not have a password in mysql). When I try using a remote connection, authentication fails with :

```
$ mysql --ssl -u user101 -p -h myserver
Enter password: 
ERROR 2059 (HY000): Authentication plugin 'dialog' cannot be loaded: /usr/lib/mysql/plugin/dialog.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

On the server, the console spits out this message:

```
# 2017 Jul 18 08:27:05 myserver pam_unix(mysql:auth): auth could not identify password for [user101]
```

Documentation [here](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pam-authentication-plugin/) mentions the `dialog` plugin but says *There is no need to install or enable anything* so not sure what to do. I did not compile or install `pam_user_map.c` as mentioned in that link as local auth worked OK.

I've given the user remote access using `%` in the hostname for the mysql entry:

```
CREATE USER 'user101'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam USING 'mariadb';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'user101'@'%' IDENTIFIED VIA pam;
```

I'm assuming the rest of  the LDAP setup (from the docs) is correct or the server would not authenticate the user locally. Is there something I'm missing? Why would this work locally, but not remotely?

Answer (score 1):

This did it (on client) 
`aptitude install libmariadbclient18`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use mysql client rather than mariadb client, you need to pass the following option:
`mysql --enable-cleartext-plugin --ssl -u user101 -p -h myserver`